# Knockout JS - Serialize a Class to JSON

Tags: json, serialization, knockout.js

I'm learning Knockout JS (awesome framework! By the way, I'm from Silverlight, MVVM powa) and I think I'm blocking on a simple thing.

I have a class `User` like this :

```
var User = function () {
    this.Login = ko.observable();
    this.FirstName = ko.observable();
    this.LastName = ko.observable();
    this.Password = ko.observable();
    this.Email = ko.observable();
};
```

And a ViewModel like this :

```
var UsersPage = function () {
    /*
    * Properties
    */
    this.self = this;
    this.users = ko.observableArray([new User()]);
    this.newUser = ko.observable(new User());

    /*
    * Methods
    */
    this.saveUser = function () {
        alert(ko.ToJSON(this.newUser()));
    };
};
```

In the HTML, I have a simple form bound to the "newUser" property. When, I submit my form, I want to serialize the property in JSON to pass it though to a WCF service. The `ko.ToJSON` doesn't seem to work. I tried several methods, but I am not getting the results I expect.

So, my question is: How do I serialize my User property to JSON?

Here is a JSFiddle to reproduce it : http://jsfiddle.net/ZfSbR/5/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

- The method is called `ko.toJSON()` and not `ko.ToJSON()` (see [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html)).
- `this.self = this` should be `var self = this` - you don't need to introduce `self` as the property.
- Best practice is to always use `self` instead of `this` in view-model's methods, because `this` may point to different object and not view-model itself.
- If you want to map observables from the user to inputs, use `newUser().property` in the `data-bind` instead of `newUser.property`.

**[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/5xNcN/)** is the modified code.

Comment: rg701653 Glad to help. I will try not to break your heart :P.